# Excel data handling

Tags: excel, vba

There is a specific requirement wherein filtering of data is to be done. For example here is a part of the large excel worksheet:

[image: Sample rows]

The requirement is to filter the data so that column A has unique values, column B, C & D should have values in accordance with column A. Also there should be a new column containing the sum of all the values of E, F & G against the unique value of column A. So, for the sample, the desired output will be like:

[image: Sample desired output]

This i just a sample, the values, no. of row/columns are variable.
I tried by creating a pivot table but the expand/collapse mechanism is not desired in the sheet. Can a vba help in this situation? Please suggest.

Comment: are the contents of columns B, C and D the same for every occurrence of the unique number?

Comment: Wouldn't an [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Advanced-filter-details-BBD0CB0A-8F90-43DF-BF77-6AD3774DC420) be appropriate for this?

Comment: ARGH I was about to post when the Q got closed 8(

Comment: @jeeped LOL good thing it got closed, I missed the vba tag and was prepared to give it a formula answer.

Comment: @ForwardEd - Just another wannabe trolling for free code without any effort of their own. I try to close these off ASAP and usually don't have to look beyond my own contributions to find something suitable. Of course, the complete lack of any original effort does make it easier to pick something that suits the bill; any actual effort shown would likely be accommodated.